# Sharepoint 2007 Workflow 'Pause for Duration' action SharePoint timer service

Tags: 2007, timer-jobs

I have several workflows that have been designed in SharePoint 2007 that use the  'Pause for Duration' action. I know that this action is dependant on the SharePoint Timer Servce.

My question is if the application server on which the SharePoint timer service runs goes down, do the workflows dependant on this service die or are they rehydrated once the service is back up again?

Thanks,
Nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I haven't verified this scenario, all data and status of the workflow is stored in the SQL database, independent from the server that runs the Timer Service. As the Timer Service only checks every few minutes (5 by default) to see if any paused workflows need to be resumed I can only assume it uses 'scheduled time <= current time' in the 'where clause'. That way it doesn't matter if it is 5 minutes later or 5 days later.

Comment: Thanks you, just trying to search for documentation regarding the interaction between the timer service and the workflows.